# jquery function not firing at all

Tags: jquery

Real Dumb question.  I figured I would have gotten this straight by now, but I am obviously missing something.  I want my function to fire as soon as the page loads to check the value of a variable and make a button appear or dissapear based on that value.  But the function I wrote never gets called.  I place the function inside a $.Load() and $(document).ready jquery call.  How can I get this function to fire?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;        
        (function () {           
        debugger;
        var $b = '<%=toggle %>';
        var buttonTog = $("#test1");
        var buttonTog1 = $("#Submit1");
        if($b=="1")
        {
            debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({
                display: 'block'
            })
            buttonTog.css({
                display: 'none'
            });
        }
        else if($b=="0")
        {
            debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({
                display: 'none'
            })
            buttonTog.css({
                display: 'block'
            });
           }            
       });
       ...
    });
```

As you can see, I have multiple debugger statements in there that just don't get hit...  When I hit $(document).ready and I get into the first debugger statement, It simply doesn't touch the next function?  I don't get it?  It goes right over it?  Can you not call a function inside the .ready(function())?  Definitly need to get some research done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You define an anonymous function but you never call it. Here's how to auto-invoke the anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function() {
        var buttonTog = $("#test1");
        var buttonTog1 = $("#Submit1");
        ...
    })(); // <!-- notice the (); at the end
});
```

This being said, I can hardly see the usefulness of using this anonymous auto-invoking function inside the `document.ready` callback which itself is an anonymous function. Things start to get really private here :-)

You could simply write the code inside it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var buttonTog = $("#test1");
    var buttonTog1 = $("#Submit1");
    ...
});
```

I suspect that you might be missing some important concepts about the `$(document).ready` function and its syntax. I would recommend you checking [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more examples.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point of the inner anonymous function anyway.

Comment: Thanks again Darin.  You have been pretty helpfull this week.  I'll look over those documents and get a better handle on all things jquery.

Answer (score 3):

just remove the `(function () {` and it's `});` will do

Answer (score 2):

You've defined your function, but you've never called it. Call it.

```
function doSomething () {           
        debugger;
        var $b = '<%=toggle %>';
        var buttonTog = $("#test1");
        var buttonTog1 = $("#Submit1");
        if($b=="1")
        {
            debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({
                display: 'block'
            })
            buttonTog.css({
                display: 'none'
            });
        }
        else if($b=="0")
        {
            debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({
                display: 'none'
            })
            buttonTog.css({
                display: 'block'
            });
           }            
       });
```

then

```
$(function(){
     doSomething(); // here, you've executed your function
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this  will work perfectly ...

Check http://jsfiddle.net/GfjHd/

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="One" id="test1" />
<input type="button" value="Two" id="Submit1" />
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
        var $b = '1';
        var buttonTog = $("#test1");
        var buttonTog1 = $("#Submit1");
        if($b=="1")
        {
            //debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({display: 'block'});
            buttonTog.css({display: 'none'});
        }
        else if($b=="0")
        {
           // debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({display: 'none'})
            buttonTog.css({display: 'block'});
         }            
    });
```