# jquery scroll to position on page on anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an anchor link that when clicked will scroll down the page.

the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scrollWin(){
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#scrollToHere").offset().top
        }, 800);
    }
});
</script>
```

the link:

```
<a class="icon_button" href="#"  onclick="scrollWin();" ><i class="icon-chevron-down "></i> </a>
```

and then the div to be scrolled to:

```
<div id="scrollToHere">
Scroll to here
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The function is called scrollWin() and you missed "r" in onclick event on the anchor tag - scollWin().

Comment: Dang thought I checked all spelling. But still does not work

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome newest version

Comment: try removing the `$(document).ready(function() {` wrapper

Comment: I agree with Bluetoft, I think wrapping it in doc ready made it in that scope so the onclick call does not work since the function does not exist

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NMSFf/

Comment: and doesn't work here http://jsfiddle.net/NMSFf/1/ which loads the function when dom is ready

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery function not firing at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152152/jquery-function-not-firing-at-all)

Comment: hey that works thanks! I don't quite understand though. Why is it not in the scope of the dom being ready? Is that for only that exact moment of it being ready I guess?

Comment: @Bluetoft if you make it as the answer I'll select it since you were first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing the '$(document).ready(function() {' wrapper

There is no need to wrap this as you're just declaring a function.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/mA34T/

```
$('#foo').click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollToHere").offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

Would that fix your issue?